# Выбор PHP фреймворка для нового проекта

Tags: zend2, php, yii, framework, symfony2

Добрый вечер! На следующей неделе начинаем разработку нового проекта, детали которого я не могу разглашать. Уже определено, что писать будем на PHP используя ООП, но не выбрали фреймворк. Выбираем из Zend2, Yii и Symfony2. Что посоветуете выбрать из трех предложенных вариантов и почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zend 2 - нет, нет и еще раз нет, он сырой. Минимум через полгода.

Zend, Yii и Symfony2 - возможно, но без спецов, которые имеют за плечами реальные проекты написанные на них с нуля, сядете на дно.

Yii - прост в изучении. Все остальное сложнее. Много инфы можно найти по Zend`у, про Symfony 2 сказать такое не могу.

Еще могу порекомендовать Kohana 3 (он тоже прост в изучении), но в любом случае без спецов глупо начинать проект, т.к. делать и переделывать будете долго.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я как-то даже не подумал про Zend2, что он еще сырой...

Comment: Symfony 2,3 - Замечательный фреймворк, но у него высокий порог вхождения. В то же время, у него отличная документация с множеством примеров и решений типовых задач.
Во всем остальном мне помогал StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Symfony2 потому что самый лучший :)) а по подробнее можно рассказать после озвучивания каких-нтть деталей ;)

Comment: Можете объяснить какие преимущества у Symfony2 перед Zend Framework 2 и Yii? Хотя бы очень кратко...

Comment: Современный и уже отточенный. Но имейте ввиду, с наскоку сф2 не осваивается, и разумеется после осваивания всё остальное будет смотреться блекло ;)

Comment: `XYZ` потому что самый лучший :)) а по подробнее можно рассказать после озвучивания каких-нтть деталей ;)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать - я не могу раскрывать секреты раньше времени, но скажу одно по сложности проект примерно как Хэшкод.

Comment: @eprivalov1

- Вам тут сейчас насоветуют, примерно [как насоветовали](http://bit.ly/Q7PF0N) в вашем предыдущем вопросе.

- Если вы собираетесь делать еще один `QA` ресурс, то намного важнее и перспективнее прочитать [вот это](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) и посмотреть, на какие грабли наступали другие разработчики.

- И да, успех такого ресурса, естественно, не в движке, а в правильном маркетинге. Поэтому, лично мое мнение - **не изобретайте велосипед, лучше присоединитесь к `opensource` разработке,** или просто возьмите движок с подходящей лицензией.

Answer (score -1):

Zend 2 - вполне можно. Очень гибкий, позволяет с помощью своих структур сделать любую архитектуру. Оттюнить как следует можно. Позволяет сделать разработку после тюна максимально комфортной и обособленной. НО он весьма сложен для понимания - 100% нужен дорогой спец, который много работал с архитектурно-сильными системами: чтобы вышло что-то хорошее. Если нету такого спеца - Yii .